# Netbeans Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have the error above. Im using netbeans and i make java gui. I connect my java gui with my sql database through MySql server. It was working properly till yesterday. Today i opened netbeans project and it redlined my code where buttons, textfields and jtables were present. It also deleted my sql connector driver and i cant even see my database on database list on services. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I dont even know what to try. Really.